# Laravel apps, DigitalOcean and CPU/RAM usage

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vue.js

I currently have a DigitalOcean VPS with 1GB and v3CPU, my apps run fine with this but I'm thinking about upgrading to the 20 dllars/month plan, however something caught my attention, the 20month plan has 3GB more of RAM but one less of CPU, this seems pretty weird to me to be honest, I don't know if laravel apps are more CPU heavy than RAM so I'm looking for some advice, I doon't want to shoot myself in the foot by upgrading to a plan which could negatively affect the performance of my apps, my webs are all middel-sized laravel apps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8XTf.png

Can someone shed some light on me?

Comment: It's going to depend on your app. If you're doing stuff like video encoding, you'll probably want the CPU. If it's a simple CRUD app, you probably need RAM more than CPU. Benchmark your app locally - everyone is different.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Digital Ocean in the past, and I know that they have a monitoring of cpu and memory usage.
You can check this statistic for last week's and decide what exactly you need to upgrade.

Because without knowledge of what you app make and which resources use it's very hard to advice.
F.ex. if you application only convert data from format A to B maybe you need more CPUs. 
But if you f.ex. load very big xmls into the memory, than you need more memory.